# Clear the textview and add the new textview while click the each category

Tags: java, android, arraylist, textview, android-linearlayout

In my Android application I have to display article title on corresponding category.

I wish to display the output in following format:

```
Languages Programming    --- Category name on Horizontal listview
```

If I have to click **Languages** which means getting the article title for that selected category alone and displaying on Horizontal listview.

```
Languages Programming

Tamil    Engilsh  Hindi Telugu
```

If I have to click **Programming** means need to display the :

```
Languages Programming

    Java  C     C++
```

Now my **current status** is :

I have to run the app and click **Languages** which means getting the output is :

```
Languages Programming

Tamil English Hindi
```

After that I have to click Programming means getting the output is :

```
Languages Programming

    Tamil English Hindi
```

What's wrong in my code? Why am getting the same output on my app screen?
But i got the correct article titles on my console window. I have facing problem only on my app screen only..

What's wrong in my code ... please give me solution for these ...

```
public void updateDetail(String categorytitle,int object) {

  lblName.setText(categorytitle);
  System.out.println("The Category name is "+categorytitle);
  String strI = Integer.toString(object+1);
  String[] stockArr = new String[Appscontent.Sub_arraylist.size()];
  stockArr = Appscontent.Sub_arraylist.toArray(stockArr);

  for (String s : stockArr)
  {
    if (s.startsWith(strI))
    {
      String _Substring;
      _Substring = s.substring(1);
      Appscontent.Sub_arraylisttwo.add(_Substring);
    }
  }

  //pass the article title
  hSroll = new HorizontalScrollView(getActivity());
  lLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
  lLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
  lLayout.setLayoutParams(lLayoutLayoutParams);
  lLayout.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
  lLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);



  for(int j = 0; j < Appscontent.Sub_arraylisttwo.size(); j++)
  {
    LinearLayout ly = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    ly.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ly.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#666666"));
    ly.setLayoutParams(articleLayoutParams);
    ly.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1); 
    ly.setOnClickListener(mArticleClick);
    ly.setId(position);
    position++;


    TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
    tv.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    tv.setText(Appscontent.Sub_arraylisttwo.get(j));
    System.out.println("The article title is "+Appscontent.Sub_arraylisttwo.get(j));

    ly.addView(tv);

    lLayout.addView(ly);

  }
  int num = Integer.parseInt(strI);
  strI = String.valueOf(num = num + 1);
  Appscontent.Sub_arraylisttwo.clear();
  Appscontent.Sub_arraylistdessub.clear();
  Appscontent.Sub_arraylistimagesub.clear();
  Appscontent.Sub_arraylistcontentsub.clear();
  Appscontent.Sub_arraylistvideosub.clear();

  hSroll.addView(lLayout);
  verticalLayout.addView(hSroll);

}
```

Please review my code and give me solution for these...am getting the correct output on my console window.But i didn't get the output on my android app screen...

**EDIT:**

My consolw output is :

When clicked **Languages** means

```
The Category name is Languages
The article title is Tamil
The article title is English
The article title is Hindi
The article title is Telugu
```

Afterthat i have clicked **Programming** means

```
The Category name is Programming
The article title is Java
The article title is c
The article title is C++
```

Comment: Please ensure your code has consistent indentation before posting. Also, please don't write your question like a text message. Use "output" not "o/p" and "problem" not "pbm".

Comment: Please add an example of your console output to your question.

Comment: @DuncanJones please see my updated code and give me solution for these.